# TypeScript fails to infer the type of a method if there are two similar classes

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XWAewHYQC4CcBXYXDfACgFsAuaAIWgB9oBhASkQF8lulRIYDZGmgAzDBnIdhItPgCmuQvizQs8gO5xyuABYBLCGwDcKNN178orRGdTjJ0u7IVKVazdr2GTzi0A)

```
class A {
    constructor(m: B | C) {}
}

class B {
    foo() {
        return new A(this);
    }
}

class C {
    foo() {
        return new A(this);
    }
}
```

`B.foo()`'s return type is correctly resolved to `A`, but `C.foo()` is `any`:

`'foo' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.`

If you reverse `m`'s type to `C | B`, `B.foo()` will return `any` and `C.foo()` will return `A`. If you make `B` and `C` somewhat more distinct from each other, in a way that `B` has something `C` doesn't (but not the other way around), they will both resolve correctly.

It's just a bit baffling to me.

Comment: It's probably a compiler bug. The compiler probably tries to do some subtype reduction and ends up comparing `foo` from the two classes before it gets a chance to have a type for `A`, resulting in the recursion. Renaming one of them to `foo2` makes everything work out. I would suggest opening an issue on GH TS repo  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript after searching for a similar issue